# Script for changing the location that symlinks point to

Tags: linux, bash

I have a few hundred symlinks I want to shift location for. Right now for example:

```
randomfile -> /home/me/randomfile
randomfile2 -> /home/me2/randomfile2
```

There are loads of files like this. Say I wanted to shift the symlinks to all be something link

```
randomfile -> ../me/randomfile
randomfile2 -> ../me2/randomfile2
```

What would be the quickest way to batch this?

Comment: What do you mean by "quick"? Do you mean "atomic", as in, it would cause bugs if they ever had inconsistent referants, and that's important enough to spend extra time writing code to maintain that constraint? Do you mean minimizing the amount of development time?

Comment: This is a once off task. Few hundred files that need symlinks changed. The change is very consistant for each file /home/ will become ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for f in *; do
  ## if not a symlink, ignore this file
  [[ -L "$f" ]] || continue
  ## determine where it points
  tgt=$(readlink "$f")
  ## if not pointing to /home/*, ignore this file
  [[ $tgt = /home/* ]] || continue
  ## calculate the new target
  new_tgt=../${tgt#/home/}
  ## actually create the new link
  ln -T -sf "$new_tgt" "$f"
done
```

This uses bash (will not work in `/bin/sh` mode) and GNU ln -- for other implementations, where `ln -T` is unavailable, extra logic may be needed when the target is a directory.